# Merge Gradient background for two divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two different divs inside the main container. consider both of them as header divs. Looks as below:

[image]

I want to merge their backgrounds as one to look like below:
[image]

I should ideally be creating a single div but in my case that's not an option.
Any tricks/ideas.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: MCVE missing, yeah ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background looks like has a green left-to-right linear gradient, can't you use the same CSS `background`? Something like:

```
div1, div2 {
    ...
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(52,247,101,1) 0%, rgba(34,115,64,1) 100%);
    ...
}
```

or, if you want you can use the same background image but with different positions:

```
div1 {
    ...
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    ...
}
div2 {
    ...
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    ...
}
```

Those were my ideas.

Comment: Thanks Davdriver. That seems like an good idea. will try it out

Comment: @Deepak Please, consider marking this as answer and closing the question if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Your example includes two separate divs, you cannot "merge" their backgrounds. To achieve the green example, you would use one div with a gradient background, and then two divs inside of it: one floating left for the "DASHBOARD" text, and one floating right for the "Filter" section.

Try this:

```css
#container {
  background: #f2f2f2; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #f2f2f2 0%, #f00f00 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #f2f2f2 0%,#f00f00 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f2f2f2 0%,#f00f00 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f2f2',endColorstr='#f00f00',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#leftDiv {
  float:left;
}

#rightDiv {
  float:right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftDiv">LEFT</div>
  <div id="rightDiv">RIGHT</div>
  
  <!-- When using floated elements, be sure to clear -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work.

I set background on body and multiple divs to transparent.

```
background-color: transparent !important;  

 body {
         
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(50% 100% 90deg,rgba(137, 213, 224, 1) 1.28%,rgba(199, 224, 201, 1) 61.89%,rgba(233, 230, 189, 1) 100%)!important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(137, 213, 224, 1) 1.28%, rgba(199, 224, 201, 1) 61.89%, rgba(233, 230, 189, 1) 100%)!important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,50% 100%,50% 0%,color-stop(0.0128,rgba(137, 213, 224, 1) ),color-stop(0.6189,rgba(199, 224, 201, 1) ),color-stop(1,rgba(233, 230, 189, 1) ))!important;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(137, 213, 224, 1) 1.28%, rgba(199, 224, 201, 1) 61.89%, rgba(233, 230, 189, 1) 100%)!important;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(137, 213, 224, 1) 1.28%, rgba(199, 224, 201, 1) 61.89%, rgba(233, 230, 189, 1) 100%)!important;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#89D5E0', endColorstr='#E9E6BD' ,GradientType=0)"!important;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(137, 213, 224, 1) 1.28%, rgba(199, 224, 201, 1) 61.89%, rgba(233, 230, 189, 1) 100%)!important;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#E9E6BD',endColorstr='#89D5E0', GradientType=0)!important;
     }
```